# Getting Account Number from array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a variable `$accountNumber` which is getting an array like this:

[image]

I want to get the accountNumber string from this array and put it inside another variable called $ac.

Basically what I am trying to achieve is 
that $ac will have the string fi4240553120051164 so I can just pass it on to my database.

Basically the code is like

```
$accountNumber = $bankReport->getAccountNumbersVerified();
// Now get the accountNumber string from $accountNumber and put it into $ac
$ac = //code here
```

Comment: what about  `$ac = $accountNumber[0]->accountNumber;`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks! that Works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Very simple.

```
$ac = $accountNumber[0]->accountNumber;
```